# how do i apply a condition when the fields are empty then it never post the data to the mysql data base

Tags: android

I am trying to post data to mysql data base and it post it. But now i am trying to apply check if the fields in activity are empty - and data isn't posted to database.

```
public class Accepter extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText etName,etAge,etCity,etContact,etQuantity;
private Spinner spBloodGroup;
private ImageView imCancel,imSave;
private String message = "POST";
private static String[] BLOOD_GROUPS = {"Select Blood Group","A +Ve","B +Ve","AB +Ve","O +Ve","A -Ve","B -Ve","AB -Ve","O -Ve"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accepter_entry_form);

    etName     = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNameAcc);
    etAge      = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAgeAcc);
    etCity     = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCityAcc);
    etContact  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNoAcc);
    etQuantity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etQuantityAcc);

    spBloodGroup = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spBloodGroupAcc);

    imCancel = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imCancelAcc);
    imSave   = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imSaveAcc);

    imCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    imSave.setOnClickListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> bgAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Accepter.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,BLOOD_GROUPS);
    bgAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spBloodGroup.setAdapter(bgAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.imSaveAcc:
        String name  = etName.getText().toString();
        String blood = spBloodGroup.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String quantity = etQuantity.getText().toString();
        String phone = etContact.getText().toString();
        int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());  
        String city = etCity.getText().toString();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month= c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day  = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String date = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month) + "-" + String.valueOf(year);

        if(name.length()>1 && blood.length()>1 && phone.length()>1 && age>15 && city.length()>1)
        {
            AccepterTask task = new AccepterTask(v.getContext());
            task.execute(message ,name, blood, phone, String.valueOf(age),city,quantity,date);
            etName.setText("");
            spBloodGroup.setSelection(0);
            etContact.setText("");
            etAge.setText("");
            etCity.setText("");
            etQuantity.setText("");
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Accepter.this, "Any field is empty or invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.imCancelAcc:
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),MainView.class);
        i.putExtra("type", "Accepter");
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}


public class AccepterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private Context context;
    private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private JSONObject json;
    private String accepter_url = //"http://192.168.0.6/accepter.php";
            "http://10.0.2.2/accepter.php";
    private String s;

    public AccepterTask(Context c)
    {
        context  = c;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        String message = params[0];

        if(message.equals("POST"))
        {
             List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             final String names = params[1];
             final String blood = params[2];
             final String phone = params[3];
             final String age   = params[4];
             final String city  = params[5];
             final String quantity = params[6];
             final String date  = params[7];

             list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", names));
             list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("blood", blood));
             list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", quantity));
             list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
             list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", age));
             list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));
             list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));

             json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(accepter_url, params[0], list);
        }
        try 
        {
            s = json.getString("message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

here for updates

Comment: what is the problem? why do you call `finish();`

Comment: Just use debugger and check what of your conditions is failing.

Comment: if(name.length()>1 && blood.length()>1 && phone.length()>1 && age>15 && city.length()>1)
        { thats the problem it doesn't work properly

Comment: What do you mean the `if(...)` is not working properly? What behavior do you expect?

Comment: i mean if the different field are empty my app show me erorr instead me toast message or empty field message

Comment: Maybe you want a dialog? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html